# How to use the equivalent of volatile in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, singleton, volatile

While learning about creating singleton objects and the problems when using them with threads in VB.NET i found the following post
[How do I specify the equivalent of volatile in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929146/how-do-i-specify-the-equivalent-of-volatile-in-vb-net)

The marked answer shows the following methods

```
Function VolatileRead(Of T)(ByRef Address As T) As T
    VolatileRead = Address
    Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()
End Function

Sub VolatileWrite(Of T)(ByRef Address As T, ByVal Value As T)
    Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()
    Address = Value
End Sub
```

But how do i use this methods in my application to create a singleton object?

Comment: The better singleton patterns don't require volatile anyway. Either use `Lazy(Of T)` or a type initializer.