# What happen when I run MemoryBarrier() exactly ? and how do it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, thread-safety, volatile

According to Web, I found the following codes, which is equivalent of C# Volatile for VB.NET.

Code reference: [How do I specify the equivalent of volatile in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929146/how-do-i-specify-the-equivalent-of-volatile-in-vb-net)

```
Function VolatileRead(Of T)(ByRef Address As T) As T
    VolatileRead = Address
    Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier() '*** I mean this line ***'
End Function

Sub VolatileWrite(Of T)(ByRef Address As T, ByVal Value As T)
    Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier() '*** I mean this line ***'
    Address = Value
End Sub
```

I want to know exactly, What does [Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier.aspx) do and how, when I execute it in above code ?

Can I write a method equivalent to **[MemoryBarrier()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier.aspx)** in C# myself?

Comment: [Good place to start](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I write a method equivalent to MemoryBarrier() in C# myself?

Yes... By looking at this table http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/

you can see that if you do a volatile read *and* a volatile write, you'll have the equivalent effect. So:

```
private volatile static int Useless = 0;

public static void MemoryBarrier()
{
    int temp = Useless;
    Useless = temp;
}
```

<strike>Note that there is no real replacement for `volatile` in VB.NET, because `volatile` fields use "half" memory barriers, not "full" memory barriers, while the methods that was suggested in that response uses a "full" memory barrier, so it is slower.</strike>

From .NET 4.5, you can simulate it in VB.NET by using [Volatile.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712891.aspx) and [Volatile.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712814.aspx)

```
public static void MemoryBarrier()
{
    int useless = 0;
    int temp = Volatile.Read(ref useless);
    Volatile.Write(ref useless, temp);
}
```

or in VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Sub MemoryBarrier()
    Dim useless As Integer = 0
    Dim value As Integer = Volatile.Read(useless)
    Volatile.Write(useless, value)
End Sub
```

Comment: thank u really about that [like](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/) but i don't understand what is the your code means ? I want to know MemoryBarrier how to work ?

Comment: @BehzadKhosravifar An explanation of what does `volatile` means and what a `MemoryBarrier` is is quite complex *and* technical. It is better if you read the "Good place to start" link they gave you and if necessary you put specific questions.